# how to use Thread inside Thread with ThreadSafty

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Is there a way where i can i use Thread inside Thread ? if so how to use that in Thread Safety Manner

I tried this Thread inside Thread where i got wrong result sometime. Please Help me how to figure out ***Thread inside Thread using Thread Safety***

```
for(int i=0; i<numExpression; i++)
{
    final int _i = i;
    final SDISQueryInfo _qryInfo = sdisQueryInfo;
    final SDISQueryComponent _qryComponent = qryCompoents;
    TCreate[i] = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            _qryComponent.prepare(_qryInfo);
        }
    });
    TCreate[i].setName(_qryInfo.getQueryTerm(_i));
    TCreate[i].start();
}
for(Thread t : TCreate)
{
    t.join();
}
```

Here in this  **_qryCompoents.prepare(_sdisQueryInfo)** is function which i am calling. This function has thread inside in it.

---

Sorry for this question i apology ..  i couldn't able to remove this question.

Comment: @sehe Sounds like a SEO question :))

Comment: Thread within a thread.... Inception?

Comment: i think you wrongly understand what i discussed... the function which i mention also consist of thread.. But it is working but it is not consistent . so i dont know why this is happening ..

Answer (score 2):

In principle there is no issue with starting threads from other threads. There is no real difference between the threads (there aren't parent threads or child threads, so to speak).

I'm not sure what you *mean* by "this function has a Thread inside it...".

I'm assuming you mean that it will start another thread. By no means does that make a big difference, unless of course that inner thread is sharing information with other threads. You'd have to consult the documentation for `SDISQueryComponent.prepare` to find out whether that is the case.

My expectation is that SDISQueryComponent is ok with threading, for the simple reason that it is obviously designed with threading in mind (or it wouldn't start threads).

The most important thing I'd think of here, is that you might run into the point where creating more threads creates contention (due to context switching overhead and perhaps locking) making things slow.

In that case, the usual solution involves a thread pool and a worker queue. However, I don't know whether SDISQueryComponent supports using a thread pool, so that might be out of your hands

Comment: Thanks for you valuable time ..

Comment: Here The code which i mention above with thread is working fine.. If i add thread inside that function the result sometime it is correct and in some time it is not showing correct result(inconsistent) .. let me add the function code also ..

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html, http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html